# Securing Location in AspNet WebApplication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, swashbuckle

I would like to secure to `swagger/docs/v1` but have no success.

I tryed some redirects inside my `global.asax` and the `<location>` header in web.config but nothing really works.

The problem is that this is served over a owin midleware so i cant use the `Authorize` attribute on a controller or action.

What is a good solution to secure the path `swagger/docs/v1` in a asp.net web application?